# Passing form data to a confirmation view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple form that I show to the user with the **Create** action. After they have submitted the form, I show them a new **Confirmation** view, where they can enter their e-mail address to be sent a copy of the form.

In order to fill out the e-mail properly, I need to retain all of the data from the `MonthlyReport` form that they just completed. However, I am finding it difficult to preserve that report data across Get and Post requests from the Confirmation view.

When I post from the Confirmation page, I find that my `ConfirmationViewModel` no longer contains a valid report.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Create(MonthlyReport model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var modelDto = _factory.CreateDataTransferObject(model);
            _repository.Submit(modelDto);

            ModelState.Clear();

            return Confirmation(model);
        }

        return Create();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Confirmation(MonthlyReport model)
    {
        var confirmation = new ConfirmationViewModel();
        confirmation.Report = model;
        return View("Confirmation", confirmation);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Confirmation(ConfirmationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var email = _mailer.MonthlyReportEmail(model);
                email.DeliverAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Sending mail failed: {0}", error));
            }

            TempData["message"] = "Confirmation e-mail sent.";
        }
        return View("Confirmation");
    }
```

Here is the Confirmation view:

```
@model Domain.Entities.ConfirmationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirmation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Monthly report for @Model.Report.LearnerName has been saved.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirmation", "MonthlyReport", Model))
{
    <h4>Enter your e-mail address to receive a copy of the report.</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailAddress)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress, new { @class = "input-field" })</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="small-submit-button" value="Send" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display the `Confirmation` view, you are passing the posted model from the `Create` action.

Once you POST the `Confirmation` form, you are posting the data in the inputs. Since you don't have inputs for the Report's properties... this information is not posted.

You have some options:

1. Add hiddens inputs for each relevant property in the Report model
2. Save the information in the server, and retrieve it once the user post the Confirmation form.  You can save the Report data in the database, `TempData` or the session.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things a bit. Now, I don't think I want to create a bunch of hidden inputs (the monthly report has a lot of fields), so option 2 is my best bet. Concerning where to save the report, what is generally considered best practice? TempData seems the simplest, but is that also the most hacky solution?

Comment: @Charlie, I think it depends in how "long" do you need to save the information. TempData is very ephemeral, it keep the information for the time of an HTTP Request. This mean only from one page to another. This also work with a 302/303 redirection because it’s in the same HTTP Request. Helps to maintain data when you move from one controller to other controller or from one action to other action. If you need to access this info again not in the context of this request, you should put it in a more persistent place (session or database).